# How can one add static methods to Java classes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Is it possible to add a new static method to the `java.lang.Math` class in `Kotlin`? Usually, such things are possible in Kotlin thanks to [Kotlin Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#companion-object-extensions).

I already tried doing the following in a file I made called `Extensions.kt`:

```
fun Math.Companion.clamp(value:Double,minValue:Double,maxValue:Double):Double
{
    return Math.max(Math.min(value,maxValue),minValue)
}
```

but `Math.Companion` could not be resolved...

Comment: Why not add the function to the Double class? `fun Double.clamp(min: Double, max Double)`, to be called like `1.0.clamp(2.0, 3.0)`.

Comment: i think it is going to be possible in the future releases

Comment: Doesn't coerceIn (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/coerce-in.html) what you need?

Comment: Yes! Thanks @SergeyMashkov, that is what I needed in this case. However, I should rephrase my question as: "How can one add static methods to Java classes in Kotlin"

Comment: @Eric Nobody can in fact. Kotlin's top-level extension functions are static functions of a facade class (generally it is $filename$Kt.class) and a receiver is just a first parameter. You can't have Math instance so you can't pass anyway. It just doesn't work like that. So general answer is: you can't and you shouldn't.

Comment: @Eric then only you can do is to declare top-level function (not extension) and put it to the specific package

Comment: @voddan it hasn't been talked about that I'm aware, please link to a Kotlin slack chat or forum discussion, or even YouTrack ticket for that feature?

Comment: @SergeyMashkov "Shouldn't" is speaking from opinion, it is obviously something that COULD be implemented in Kotlin using a different form of the function that either takes the Java/Kotlin class as the receiver or is receiver-less.    Currently, there is no way to do this without a Companion object being declared.  But nothing prevents such a feature in the future as compiler syntactic sugar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static extension methods in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210188/static-extension-methods-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update on top of other answers: Static extensions will be available right after 2.0

Official announement: [kotlin conf 2023](https://youtu.be/c4f4SCEYA5Q?t=776)

Answer (score 53):

As of Kotlin 1.3, this is not possible. However, it's being considered for a future release!

To help this feature get implemented, go vote on this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968

Because all proposals are basically in limbo right now, I wouldn't hold my breath that this will get in any time soon

Comment: To whoever falls in this answer, please vote up the jetbrains post so we can have that feature earlier!

Comment: As of today the feature request remains open.

Comment: _This idea is very popular in the Kotlin community, so I bet it'll be in soon enough_ . Aug 2022 Issue is still open.

Comment: @apouche YUP! Basically all movement was halted once Roman Elizarov took over. I'm still salty.

Comment: This is now a proposal for Kotlin 2.0 at https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/348

Answer (score 15):

I think this is not possible. [Documentation says](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#companion-object-extensions) the following:

> If a class has a companion object defined, you can also define extension functions and properties for the companion object.

The `Math` class is a `Java` class, not a `Kotlin` one and does not have a `companion` object in it. You can add a `clamp` method to the `Double` class instead.

Answer (score 3):

As of Kotlin 1.2 it is still not possible.

As a workaround, to statically "extend" Environment class I am currently using:

```
Class EnvironmentExtensions {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun getSomething(): File {
            ...
            return Environment.something()
        }
    }
}
```

It is not an ideal solution but IntelliJ/Android Studio code completion helps with the usage:

```
val something = EnvironmentExtensions.getSomething()
```