# How can I extension Java class with Kotlin to use like static fun?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

```
public class TestA {
     public static void a() {}
} 

fun TestA.b(){}
```

How can I extension Java class with Kotlin to use like static fun ?
just like `TestA.b()` to use this fun

Comment: Do you need to call Java static function from Kotlin? Or do you want to extend Java class with static function?

Comment: I don't think it possible, you can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911457/how-can-one-add-static-methods-to-java-classes-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is currently not yet supported to statcally extend a Java-Class. See the corresponding issue

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968