# Prerequisite to create extension function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-methods

I am learning Kotlin. As per I learnt, extension functions provides the ability to extend a class with new functionality without having to inherit from the class. I am creating extension function for `okhttp3.RequestBody`. But I am not able to get method in my activity.

Here is my extension function:

```
fun RequestBody.createPlainRequestBody(message: String): RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), message)
```

while calling function as below I am getting unresolved function

```
RequestBody.createPlainRequestBody()
```

while I am creating extension function for toast I am getting perfect result as below:

```
fun Context.showToast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

by calling:

```
this@MainActivity.showToast("Upload successfully")
```

Can any one guide for how to resolve this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911457/how-can-one-add-static-methods-to-java-classes-in-kotlin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension functions can be applied to instances of a particular class, but you're trying to call it on a class, as if it were a static method. Moreover, your extension function expects an argument and you're not providing any.

What you need in your case is a simple function that creates a `RequestBody` as you're not acting on any particular instance of `RequestBody`.

Under the hood an extension function is simply a static method where the first argument is the receiver object and any other argument is shifted by one. Your `showToast` extension function is equivalent to the following Java snippet:

```
public static void showToast(Context receiver, String message) {
    Toast.makeText(receiver, message, ...).show();
}
```

That's why you can call Kotlin extension functions from Java.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, you cannot do this in `OkHttp` version 3, however, you
>   will able to do this in `OkHttp4` which is being rewritten completely in
>   Kotlin, so all the classes will be compatible with Koltin.

You have to extends to its companion object. (You need to make sure that class has a companion object associated with it)

```
fun RequestBody.Companion.createPlainRequestBody(message: String): RequestBody {
   return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), message)
}
```

And after that, you will be able to call it directly from its class.

```
RequestBody.createPlainRequestBody("message")
```

Or

```
RequestBody.Companion.createPlainRequestBody("message")
```

A companion object is a normal object that associated with or belongs to the class it's similar to `static` object in Java. In Kotlin, it's called `companion object`.

Comment: Thank you for these information. I will try with okhttp4 as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Nik See here https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/RequestBody.kt