# Is there a way to define a companion object outside of a class definition in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, companion-object

As far as I know, one defines a companion object within the class declaration in Kotlin,

```
class Foo {
    companion object { /* etc etc */ }
}
```

Suppose class `Foo` is already defined, without a companion object. Is there a way to equip `Foo` with a companion object afterwards?

I tried a couple of things;

```
val Foo.Companion = Foo ()
```

provokes the error message "extension property cannot be initialized because it has no backing field", and

```
Foo.Companion = Foo ()
```

provokes "unresolved reference: Companion".

Is there a way to get some assignment to `Foo.Companion` to work, such that it would be equivalent to whatever is generated automatically by the compiler in the case of `companion object` within the class definition?

Comment: Relevant, and maybe it answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911457/how-can-one-add-static-methods-to-java-classes-in-kotlin

Comment: Hmm, I gather from the comments that the answer is no at present, but coming real soon now (Kotlin 2.something, I guess).

Comment: Why do you want to add a companion object to an existing class? Depending on your use case, there may be alternative solutions, such as possibly extension functions.

Comment: @k314159 Well, I am working with some classes which have functions in the companion class to parse a string. I am thinking, perhaps naively, that it would be great to define such a function for some other classes which lack it.