# kotlin, how to add extension function to already defined class companion object

Tags: kotlin, companion-object

i want to add some extension function to an already defined class‘s companion object, like

```
fun Toast.Companion.showImageToast(str : String) {
}
```

and also i like to do the same thing on interfaces, e.g

```
fun Runnable.Companion.mainHandler() {
}
```

I've consulted the documentation, only to find syntax for define extension function for companion object in a user defined class, not for class that don't have a companion object

can i have any chance to do this in kotlin ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.0, if a class does not define a companion object, it is not possible to define extension functions for that companion object. It's also not possible to define extension functions for Java classes and interfaces such as `Runnable`.

Comment: thx guy, I've got your answer in another post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023617/is-it-possible-to-add-static-extension-function-for-java-class)