# How can I write extension methods for Array's Companion objects in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

As we know (mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210188/static-extension-methods-in-kotlin), countless people writing the same answer), we can have extension methods for companion objects to make something look like a "static extension".

But when I tried this on `kotlin.Array`, I failed:

```
operator fun <T> Array<T>.Companion.invoke() {
}
```

The code above causes this error:

[image]

So does `Array`s have companion objects? If no, how can I make "static extension"s for `Array`s?

Edit:

```
inline operator fun <reified T> Array<T>.Companion.invoke() {
}
```

This code fails, too.

Comment: I think it's still impossible to do that, as you can see [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33853233/4778343)

Comment: Also, if it did work, it would be `Array.Companion.invoke()`; the companion object doesn't depend on generic parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in Kotlin currently. The core problem with adding this here is that `kotlin.Array` does not currently have a companion object, and you can't add an extension on a companion object that does not exist.

According to [this thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/companion-object-and-function-extension/1921/7), there is no way to add a extension function to a companion object that does not exist, but people are asking for it.

The best answer in that thread I can find is from @yole:

> This feature is not on the roadmap for Kotlin 1.2; we haven’t done any planning for subsequent versions yet.

**Edit**: I found [KT-11968](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968), which seems to cover this case and has some interest from other people. Perhaps lobby for that to be included in some future release? Note that I found several other issues that seemed to fit this description but were all marked duplicates of [KT-11968](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968), so I think that's the one to upvote/lobby.