# Generic extension function Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-extension

Since getParcelable is deprecated for Android Tiramisu and later i want to make an extension function to get the parcelables from my Intent through my Bundle

So i have

```
            val server = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
                it.getParcelable("server", Server::class.java)
            } else {
                it.getParcelable("server")
            }
```

And i want to create an extension for every model like this

```
fun <T> T.getParcelable(bundle: Bundle, key: String): T? = 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        bundle.getParcelable(key, this!!::class.java)
    else
        bundle.getParcelable(key)
```

However, when i try to use it i get an unresolved reference error
[image]

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64797215/7002689)?

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> KClass<T>.getParcelable(bundle: Bundle, key: String): T? =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        bundle.getParcelable(key, T::class.java)
    else
        bundle.getParcelable(key)
```

And you use it like this

```
val server = Server::class.getParcelable(bundle, "server")
```

Comment: Nope. Plenty of errors..! Have you tried it?

Comment: I edited my original post @james04

Answer (score 1):

Extension functions are actually `static` methods on `initialised` variables & not exactly on classes. That's why it isn't working.

What you can do is:

1. You can either make your `Server` an `object`.
2. Add a blank `companion object { }` to your `Server` class & use the below extension function.

```kotlin
fun <T> T.getParcelable(bundle: Bundle, key: String): T? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        bundle.getParcelable(key, this!!::class.java)
    } else bundle.getParcelable(key)
}
```

Example usage:

```kotlin
intent?.extras?.let { bundle ->
    val server = Server.getParcelable(bundle, "server")
}
```

Edit: Alternatively, the below can also be done which is a better option:
`val server = Server::class.getParcelable(bundle, "server")`

Comment: Your answer seems correct, however i wouldn't like to do this to all my models.